# R: na.locf not behaving as expected

Tags: r, zoo

I am trying to use the `na.locf` function in a mutate and I am getting a strange answer.  The data is ordered desc by date and then if a column is NA gets the result from na.locf and otherwise uses the value in the column.  For most of the data, the answer is being returned as expected, but one row is coming back not as the previous non-NA but as the next non-NA.  If we order the data by date ascending and use na.rm = F and fromLast = T it works as expected, but I want to understand why the result is not working if date is ordered descending.

The example is as follows:

```
example = data.frame(Date = factor(c("1/14/15", "1/29/15", "2/3/15", 
    "2/11/15", "2/15/15", "3/4/15","3/7/15",  "3/7/15", "3/11/15", 
    "3/18/15", "3/21/15", "4/22/15", "4/22/15", "4/23/15", "5/6/15", 
    "5/13/15", "5/18/15", "5/24/15", "5/26/15", "5/28/15", "5/29/15", 
    "5/29/15", "6/25/15", "6/25/15","8/6/15",  "8/15/15", "8/20/15", 
    "8/22/15", "8/22/15", "8/29/15")),
   Scan = c(1, rep(NA, 21),2,rep(NA,7)),
   Hours = c(rep(NA,3), rep(3,3), NA, 2, rep(3,3), NA, 2, 3, 2, 
    rep(3,5), NA, 2, rep(c(NA, 3),2), 3, NA, 2, 3)
                   )
example %>% 
  mutate(
     date = as.Date(Date, "%m/%d/%y"),
     Hours = replace_na(Hours,0),
     scan_date = as.Date(ifelse(is.na(Scan), 
                            NA,
                            date),
                       origin="1970-01-01")) %>% 
  arrange(desc(date)) %>%
  mutate(
         scan_new = ifelse(is.na(Scan),
                na.locf(Scan), 
                Scan))
```

The issue in the result is in row 24, the Scan is coming in as 1 rather than 2:

```
      Date Scan Hours       date  scan_date scan_new
23  3/7/15   NA     0 2015-03-07       <NA>        2
24  3/7/15   NA     2 2015-03-07       <NA>        1
25  3/4/15   NA     3 2015-03-04       <NA>        2
```

Interestingly, other data with the same date is handled appropriately, for example on line 18-19

```
      Date Scan Hours       date  scan_date scan_new
18 4/22/15   NA     0 2015-04-22       <NA>        2
19 4/22/15   NA     2 2015-04-22       <NA>        2
```

For reference as noted above, the following provides the expected answer:

```
example %>% 
  mutate(
     date = as.Date(Date, "%m/%d/%y"),
     Hours = replace_na(Hours,0),
     scan_date = as.Date(ifelse(is.na(Scan), 
                            NA,
                            date),
                       origin="1970-01-01")) %>% 
  arrange(desc(date)) %>%
  mutate(
         scan_new = ifelse(is.na(Scan),
                na.locf(Scan, na.rm = F, fromLast = T), 
                Scan))

      Date Scan Hours       date  scan_date scan_new
6   3/4/15   NA     3 2015-03-04       <NA>        2
7   3/7/15   NA     0 2015-03-07       <NA>        2
8   3/7/15   NA     2 2015-03-07       <NA>        2
```

Can someone tell me why this is behaving this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first try `na.locf(Scan)`, the leading `NA`s are removed and the remaining values are recycled to the full length in the `ifelse`. You can see the results with `na.rm = F`(or `na.locf0`, see comments) for reference:

```
example %>% 
    mutate(
        date = as.Date(Date, "%m/%d/%y"),
        Hours = replace_na(Hours,0),
        scan_date = as.Date(ifelse(is.na(Scan), 
            NA,
            date),
            origin="1970-01-01")) %>% 
    arrange(desc(date)) %>%
    mutate(
        scan_new = ifelse(is.na(Scan),
            na.locf(Scan, na.rm = FALSE), 
            Scan))

#       Date Scan Hours       date  scan_date scan_new
# 1  8/29/15   NA     3 2015-08-29       <NA>       NA
# 2  8/22/15   NA     0 2015-08-22       <NA>       NA
# 3  8/22/15   NA     2 2015-08-22       <NA>       NA
# 4  8/20/15   NA     3 2015-08-20       <NA>       NA
# 5  8/15/15   NA     3 2015-08-15       <NA>       NA
# 6   8/6/15   NA     0 2015-08-06       <NA>       NA
# 7  6/25/15    2     0 2015-06-25 2015-06-25        2
# 8  6/25/15   NA     3 2015-06-25       <NA>        2
# 9  5/29/15   NA     0 2015-05-29       <NA>        2
# 10 5/29/15   NA     2 2015-05-29       <NA>        2
# 11 5/28/15   NA     3 2015-05-28       <NA>        2
# 12 5/26/15   NA     3 2015-05-26       <NA>        2
# 13 5/24/15   NA     3 2015-05-24       <NA>        2
# 14 5/18/15   NA     3 2015-05-18       <NA>        2
# 15 5/13/15   NA     3 2015-05-13       <NA>        2
# 16  5/6/15   NA     2 2015-05-06       <NA>        2
# 17 4/23/15   NA     3 2015-04-23       <NA>        2
# 18 4/22/15   NA     0 2015-04-22       <NA>        2
# 19 4/22/15   NA     2 2015-04-22       <NA>        2
# 20 3/21/15   NA     3 2015-03-21       <NA>        2
# 21 3/18/15   NA     3 2015-03-18       <NA>        2
# 22 3/11/15   NA     3 2015-03-11       <NA>        2
# 23  3/7/15   NA     0 2015-03-07       <NA>        2
# 24  3/7/15   NA     2 2015-03-07       <NA>        2
# 25  3/4/15   NA     3 2015-03-04       <NA>        2
# 26 2/15/15   NA     3 2015-02-15       <NA>        2
# 27 2/11/15   NA     3 2015-02-11       <NA>        2
# 28  2/3/15   NA     0 2015-02-03       <NA>        2
# 29 1/29/15   NA     0 2015-01-29       <NA>        2
# 30 1/14/15    1     0 2015-01-14 2015-01-14        1
```

Comment: `na.locf0` ensures output is same length as input.  See `?na.locf0` for more info.

Comment: Sorry - I am still not understanding.  Comparing your function to the first one I was asking about, I see the difference is the addition of `na.rm = F` and as a result, line 24 returns a 2.  Why does omitting `na.rm =F` make a row in the middle of the pack return a 1 rather than a 2?

Comment: @mrpargeter, when `na.rm=F` is ommitted, you got 24 values instead of 30 values. The 24 values correspond to row 7 yo row 30, but you put them in row 1 to row 24.The value 1 is the correct results for row 30, which now goes to row 24. That's why you got a 1 for row 24. for rows after row 24, the 24 values are used up and recycled from begining of the 24 values.